# Why does "quickly share --ppa share" abort with a "can't create" error?

Tags: application-development, ppa, quickly

I can not figure out what I am doing wrong. The package builds ok with `quickly package`, I could submit it, but I can not update my ppa. Here is what I got:

```
desgua@desguai7:~/quickly/sbk$ quickly share --ppa sbk
Get Launchpad Settings
Launchpad connection is ok
..........An error has occurred when creating debian packaging
ERROR: can't create or update ubuntu package
ERROR: share command failed
Aborting
```

**Edit**

The name of my ppa was wrong, but even using ppa:desgua/sbk still doesn't work:

```
desgua@desguai7:~/quickly/sbk$ quickly share --ppa ppa:desgua/sbk
Get Launchpad Settings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/quickly/templates/ubuntu-application/share.py", line 101, in 
    launchpad = launchpadaccess.initialize_lpi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/quickly/launchpadaccess.py", line 91, in initialize_lpi
    allow_access_levels=["WRITE_PRIVATE"])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 539, in login_with
    credential_save_failed, version)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 359, in _authorize_token_and_login
    service_root, cache, timeout, proxy_info, version)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 198, in __init__
    credentials, service_root, cache, timeout, proxy_info, version)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/resource.py", line 460, in __init__
    self._wadl = self._browser.get_wadl_application(self._root_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 299, in get_wadl_application
    response, content = self._request(url, media_type=wadl_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 242, in _request
    str(url), method=method, body=data, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 211, in _request_and_retry
    url, method=method, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1414, in request
    (response, new_content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 126, in _request
    LaunchpadOAuthAwareHttp, self)._request(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 130, in _request
    redirections, cachekey)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1196, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1138, in _conn_request
    raise ServerNotFoundError("Unable to find the server at %s" % conn.host)
httplib2.ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at api.launchpad.net
ERROR: share command failed
Aborting
```

Any ideas? How could I troubleshot this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To troubleshot it I add --verbose:  `quickly share --verbose --ppa desgua/sbk`.

Also a gpg and a rsa key are needed and must be published in the launchpad.

This command may have helped: `python setup.py build`

Also I have to check the file "name_version_source.changes" and the file "./sbk/debian/changelog" and make sure that the "Changed-By: Andre Desgualdo Pereira " is the same as the output of "gpg -K"

Answer (score 2):

`sbk` is not a PPA. Something like `ppa:robinj/gtkreddit` is.

I'm guessing this is yours; `ppa:desgua/sbk`.

I don't think this is the current problem though. Try `quickly package` first. Does it succeed?

Comment: Thank you very much RobinJ. Yes `quickly package` succeeds. You are rigth, looking at https://launchpad.net/~desgua/+archive/sbk I think the ppa is desgua/sbk but the command still doesn't work. At least I am getting some errors now that I can search for.

Comment: `httplib2.ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at api.launchpad.net`
Check your connection? I don't know it just seems to feel to connect to Launchpad. Are you using a proxy or anything?

Comment: The connection is ok. I'm in another computer now and the command `quickly share --ppa ppa:desgua/sbk` complains about not finding the ppa, but the command `quickly share --ppa desgua/sbk` says `An error has occurred when creating debian packaging`.

Comment: `quickly package`

Comment: `quickly package` runs successfully and the deb is working ok.

Comment: Can you `ping api.launchpad.net`?

Comment: The ping is ok `64 bytes from wildcard-launchpad-net.banana.canonical.com (91.189.89.225): icmp_req=2 ttl=49 time=197 ms`

Comment: Ok, then it's a bug. Report it on Launchpad. There's probably nothing else we can do about it.