# ValueError when running quickly share

Tags: application-development, ppa, launchpad, quickly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does “quickly share --ppa share” abort with a “can't create” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155997/why-does-quickly-share-ppa-share-abort-with-a-cant-create-error)

I have successfully created and packaged a Quickly application, and I would like to upload it to my PPA. When I run `quickly submitubuntu --ppa ppa:techsavvy8989/test`, I get the following error:

```
Get Launchpad Settings
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/quickly/templates/ubuntu-application/share.py", line 101, in <module>
    launchpad = launchpadaccess.initialize_lpi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/quickly/launchpadaccess.py", line 91, in initialize_lpi
    allow_access_levels=["WRITE_PRIVATE"])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 539, in login_with
    credential_save_failed, version)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 359, in _authorize_token_and_login
    service_root, cache, timeout, proxy_info, version)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 198, in __init__
    credentials, service_root, cache, timeout, proxy_info, version)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/resource.py", line 460, in __init__
    self._wadl = self._browser.get_wadl_application(self._root_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 299, in get_wadl_application
    response, content = self._request(url, media_type=wadl_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 242, in _request
    str(url), method=method, body=data, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 211, in _request_and_retry
    url, method=method, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1346, in request
    info, content = cached_value.split('\r\n\r\n', 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
ERROR: share command failed
Aborting
```

What did I do wrong?